# Java- Interface makes use of an interface

Tags: java, interface

I'm studying code. I 've found these two classes. I  don't understand how they are related. What does the Expression "T extends PieceType" mean, what does the T stand for?

piece.java:

```
public interface Piece<T extends PieceType> {

    /**
     * Returns the color.
     * @return the color
     */
    PieceColor getColor();    

    /**
     * Returns the type.
     * @return the type
     */
    T getType();
}
```

pieceType.java:

```
public interface PieceType {

    /**
     * Returns the type's base rating.
     * @return the base rating within range [0, 1000]
     */
    double getRating();
}
```

Comment: You need to read about Generics. Start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: After you digest that, move on to [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, it means that the type, T, that you pass into Piece must extend PieceType.

Here we have an interface that extends PieceType:

```
public interface NewPiece extends PieceType {
    ...
}
```

You would then instantiate a Piece object by doing this:

```
Piece<NewPiece> aPiece = new SomeImplementationOfPiece<NewPiece>();
```

Because NewPiece extends PieceType as given in your definition:

```
public interface Piece<T extends PieceType> { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

The interface `Piece` is [generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), and its single type parameter `T` must implement `PieceType`, as indicated by `T extends PieceType`. It might behoove you to read further into generics; the linked lesson should be a good start.